# C# from array create an non-adjacent subset

Tags: c#, arrays, subset

I want to create an subset from an array

`array  =[-2,1,3,-4,5]`

I want the subset like this below.

[-2, 3, 5] [-2, 3] [-2, -4] [-2, 5] [1, -4] [1, 5] [3, 5]

```
    -before the elements should be skipped one element
    -2,3,5
     1 -4
     3.5
    -then for each element, one neighbor should be skipped and the others taken one by  one, forming pairs (without repeating the above)
    -2,3
    -2, -4
    -2.5
     1, -4 (do not take above have)
     3.5 ((we do not have above)
    -1.5

     //This is my code.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] kume = { -3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        String[] altkume = new string[10];
        String s = "";
        for(int m = 0; m<7; m++)
        {
            int b = m;
            s += "[";
            for (int j = 0; j < kume.Length; j += 2)
            {                    
                if ((b & 1) == 0)
                {
                    s += kume[j].ToString() + ",";
                }
                b = b >> 1;                      
            }
            s += "]" + "\n";
            altkume[m] = s;

        }


        for(int i = 0; i<altkume.Length; i++)
        {


            Console.WriteLine(altkume[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
Output: 
[-3,5,7,]
[5,7,]
[-3,7,]
[7,]
[-3,5,]
[5,]
[-3,]
```

But i dont want  like this [5,]  [-3,] [7,]

I talked about problem. does anyone help ?

Comment: "I want to create an subset but the subset shouldnt be discontiguous in near." Eeeehm, what? I don´t understand your question. Please provide some sample data and what you expect as output.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "but the subset shouldnt be discontiguous in near", but at the end of your post it appears your problem is only with the ouput formatting? In that case, create your subsets as int arrays, and use `String.Join(",", array)` for placing separators between elements.

Comment: I don´t get how you plan to transform this array `array  =[-2,1,3,-4,5]` into `[-2, 3, 5] [-2, 3] [-2, -4] [-2, 5] [1, -4] [1, 5] [3, 5]`. What´s the logic here?

Comment: I want it [-2,1] shoulndt be or [1,3] or [-4,5] or [3,-4] because shouldnt side by side.

Comment: Can your tell your rules in plain text. It's like the quiz in an intelligence test, to find a rule from your samples ... should be like this/and not like that.
If you cannot describe the task to us, you cannot describe it to the computer either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a handy extension that will return the output you seek:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<List<T>> GetNonAdjacentSubsets<T>
    (
        this IEnumerable<T> source, // the collection we are evaluating
        int min_distance,           // minimum gap between numbers
        List<T> subset = null       // stores the progress of the subset we are evaluating
    )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count(); i++)
        {
            var new_subset = new List<T>(subset ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>())
            {
                source.ElementAt(i)
            };

            if (new_subset.Count > 1) //return subsets of more than one element
                yield return new_subset;

            if (source.Count() < 2) //end of list reached
                yield break;

            foreach (var ss in source.Skip(i + min_distance).GetNonAdjacentSubsets(min_distance, new_subset))
                yield return ss;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var arr = new int[] { -2, 1, 3, -4, 5 };
var subsets = new List<List<int>>(arr.GetNonAdjacentSubsets(2));
```

Output:

> -2, 3
>
> -2, 3, 5
>
> -2, -4
>
> -2, 5
>
> 1, -4
>
> 1, 5
>
> 3, 5

Comment: Thank you so much i think i get the code. But i dont understand how can i use and show.

Comment: @Ozge [Here's an example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7yEgpP), let me know if you still have questions

Comment: i am really appreciate it.